# Licensing a java web based application

Tags: java, licensing

I am developing a web application that will be sold later on, and was wondering how to add the concept of license to it, so that I can avoid it's piracy, and it can be used for given period of time only?

Comment: Hosting the web application yourself is the only way to go.

Comment: So your question is not really about "licensing" (e.g. "which license to use", "can I use this library in a commercial product", "how much should I take for this?"), but more about license enforcement.

Comment: @netbrain - cant it be something like the app gets disabled in case it exceeds the time it is allowed to run..

Comment: @Joachim - yes its more on license enforcement

Comment: @netbrain: I don't think it's the only way, but **iff** strict license enforcement is desired (and I'm still not sure that it's a good business decision), then it's one of the safest ways to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a centralize licence server , have a DB to check user's status , expose this thing using webservice so that any of your app can consume it.

Comment: nice suggestion will try implementing it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Java enterprise tools do the usual serial number/license file thing. Worked pretty well for them. All you'd need to do is put some static code in the application that would execute when the JavaEE container loads the WAR file and have that check the serial number.